# Installing SciPy with anaconda, .sh file not found

Tags: python, macos, bash, installation, scipy

I'm trying to get SciPy on python 2.7 on OSX 10.10 working.
I downloaded and installed anaconda, as the SciPy website (https://www.continuum.io/downloads) suggests, so far so good.
After installing I should run the line:

`bash Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` (in the terminal I suppose?)

When I do this it says:

```
-bash: Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong? It's probably a very basic mistake, I'm not (yet) used to installing libraries. 
Is there a certain folder where anaconda (and the .pkg file) should be saved? 
Should I run the line in Python, and if so, where should I save everything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file doesn't exist in the directory you are in when you try to issue the command to run it, so it doesn't know what to run.  Where did you save the file?  Typing `ls` should list the files in the current directory.  You will need to either navigate to the directory that contains the file before issuing the command and put the symbol "." in front to indicate you are in the relevant directory, or write the path explicitly:  i.e. `./Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` or `/this/is/the/full/path/Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh`.

Comment: My guess is that the .sh file is inside the .pkg file. When I type 'ls' in the terminal when in the directory where the .pkg file is it lists the .pkg file but not what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

change directory to the place where you downloaded it first (usually ~/Downloads/) ,change the script to be executable, then run it.

```
cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x ./Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
./Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: When I change the directory to the file path where the .pkg file is, and rune the 'chmod +x ./Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh' line it says: 'chmod: ./Anaconda2-2.4.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory'.
Could it be that the Anaconda2-rest-.sh file is just some kind of typo or so?

Comment: Yes, or you don't have the file downloaded, or you have your downloads path in your browser changed, or ... or.... or.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the instructions on the site say, if you read them:

If you downloaded the `.pkg` file (the "graphical installer"), it is installed as you usually install programs in OSX, double click the .pkg file. You don't need to run the `bash` command in this case.

If you downloaded the command-line installer `.sh` file, then you need to install using the `bash` command (in the directory where the downloaded file is).

Comment: The site says that after downloading I should run the line. If I understand it wrong, any idea why SciPy is still not working after installing?